# Java version of matlab's linspace

Tags: java, matlab

Is there a java version of matlab's colon operator or linspace? For instance, I'd like to make a for loop for evenly spaced numbers, but I don't want to bother with creating an array of those numbers manually.

For example to get all integers from 1 to 30, in matlab I would type:

```
1:30
```

or

```
linspace(1,30)
```

Comment: `linspace(a,b)` returns 100 values linearly spaced from a to b. It is not the same as `a:b` but the same as `a:((b-a)/99):b`. `linspace(1,30,30)` is the same as `1:30`.

Comment: One thing to note is that [LINSPACE and the colon operator in MATLAB can actually differ slightly in their results when generating floating-point values](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=789). The algorithm used by the colon operator to generate values is discussed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4FLI96/index.html?solution=1-4FLI96).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the two variable call, @x4u is correct.  The three variable call will be quite a bit harder to emulate.

For instance, i think that linspace(1,30,60) should produce values 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5..., or maybe that's the values for linspace(1,30,59)--either way, same problem.

With this format you'll have to do the calculations yourself--Personally I'd create a new object to do the whole thing for me and forget the for loop.

```
counter=new Linspace(1,30,60);
while(counter.hasNext()) {
    process(counter.getNextFloat())
}
```

or simply

```
while(float f : new Linspace(1,30,60)) {
    process(f);
}
```

if you have your Linspace object implement Iterable.

Then the inside of the counter object should be pretty obvious to implement and it will easily communicate to you what it is doing without obfuscating your code with a bunch of numeric calculations to figure out ratios.

An implementation might be something like this:
(NOTE: Untested and I'm pretty sure this would be vulnerable to edge cases and floating point errors!  It also probably won't handle end < start for backwards counting, it's just a suggestion to get you going.)

```
public class Linspace {
    private float current;
    private final float end;
    private final float step;
    public Linspace(float start, float end, float totalCount) {
        this.current=start;
        this.end=end;
        this.step=(end - start) / totalCount;
    }
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current < (end + step/2); //MAY stop floating point error
    }
    public float getNextFloat() {
        current+=step;
        return current;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to do this?

```
for( int number = 1; number <= 30; ++number )
```

If you need them spaced by a fixed amount, i.e. `3` you can write it this way:

```
for( int number = 1; number <= 30; number += 3 )
```

The left part of the `for` loop initializes the variable, the middle part is the condition that gets evaluated before each iteration and the right part gets executed after each iteration.

Answer (score 4):

I actually just had to do this for a java project I am working on.  I wanted to make sure it was implemented in the same way as in MATLAB, so I first wrote a MATLAB equivalent:

```
function result = mylinspace(min, max, points)  
answer = zeros(1,points);  
    for i = 1:points  
answer(i) = min + (i-1) * (max - min) / (points - 1);  
end  
result = answer;
```

I tested this against the built-in linspace function and it returned the correct result, so I then converted this to a static java function:

```
public static double[] linspace(double min, double max, int points) {  
    double[] d = new double[points];  
    for (int i = 0; i < points; i++){  
        d[i] = min + i * (max - min) / (points - 1);  
    }  
    return d;  
}
```

In my opinion this is much simpler than creating a new class for this one function.

Answer (score 1):

I think Bill K got the right idea, but I think there is no need to have a Linspace class.

```
// If you write linspace(start,end,totalCount) in Matlab ===>

for(float i = start; i < end; i += (end-start)/totalCount)
    something(i);
```

Comment: Didn't think through the fact that floats would work fine in a for loop.  Still, with float error your condition won't always work right, between that and other problems, I'd rather keep stuff centralized.  Also I think the for(float f : Linspace) is cleaner and more obvious code (adding a class usually helps readability)

Comment: Why won't it work right? Float rounding errors lead to problems if you compare i == end, but not if compare with <, <=, >, or >= which is fine indeed. Also, if you want to use Linspace in a for-each loop, then it must implement Iterable and thus it's a bit more complex to implement (you need to implement an iterator class too, and place hasNext() and next() therein). Finally, it must be an Iterable<? extends Number>, which means that every number will be wrapped into an object and then unwrapped at run-time, and this may be inefficient if you are iterating over large intervals.

Comment: Oh, and-- the compiler will actually reject any code trying to for-each-iterate over a Linspace, with the current Linspace code which is in your post, because it does not implement Iterable correctly.

Comment: If it is supposed to hit right on the button (say end at, 50.0) and it has an error that can be 50.0001 or 49.9998--this will cause an off by one error one way or another.  You can fix it by adding or subtracting a small amount, but then you copy your fix every time you use it.  Also the intent is hidden in this code where it can be made obvious if you create an obect, and that solution is easier to read--why not use an object? You are correct though, it doesn't implement iterable yet--if you can't figure out how to do it I can do it for you--I just thought it would be straight-forward to add.

Comment: By the way, I don't think "Linspace" is obvious except to people who use it--the target of my answer.  if it were me I'd call it "iterateOver" or something.

Answer (score 1):

I was myself looking for a solution for this problem and investigated how MatLab implements its Linspace. I more or less converted it to Java and ended up with the method below. As far as I have tested it works quite nicely and you get the endpoints. There is probably floating point errors as with most cases.

I am not sure if there are Copyright issues with this though.

```
public static List<Double> linspace(double start, double stop, int n)
{
   List<Double> result = new ArrayList<Double>();

   double step = (stop-start)/(n-1);

   for(int i = 0; i <= n-2; i++)
   {
       result.add(start + (i * step));
   }
   result.add(stop);

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use Java Streams, one option would be:

```
    public static Stream<Double> linspace(double start, double end, int numPoints) {
        return IntStream.range(0, numPoints)
            .boxed()
            .map(i -> start + i * (end - start) / (numPoints - 1));
    }
```

Comment: Or, for an increase by 1, `IntStream.rangeClosed(0, numPoints).toArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the main algo that works for matlab, you may convert this to Java with all the OOP details at your disposal:

```
>>> st=3;ed=9;num=4;
>>> linspace(st,ed,num)

ans =

     3     5     7     9
>>> % # additional points to create (other than 3)
>>> p2c=num-1;
>>> % 3 is excluded when calculating distance d.
>>> a=st;
>>> d=ed-st;
>>> % the increment shall calculate without taking the starting value into consideration.
>>> icc=d/p2c;

>>> for idx=[1:p2c];
a(idx+1)=a(idx)+icc;
end;
>>> a

a =

     3     5     7     9

>>> diary off
```